# Typedef for templated struct with namespaces

Tags: c++

I have three files:

position.h:

```
namespace X {
namespace Y {
namespace Z {

template<typename T1 = long, typename T2 = long>
struct Position {
};

}}}
```

class_from_api.h

```
#include "position.h"

typedef X::Y::Z::Position<> Position;

namespace X {
namespace Y {
namespace Z {

class ClassFromAPI {
    Position<> p;  // why not Position?
};

}}}

typedef X::Y::Z::ClassFromAPI ClassFromAPI;
```

user_class.h:

```
#include "class_from_api.h"

Class UserClass : public ClassFromAPI {
    Position p;
};
```

and my question is: **Why do I have to write in ClassFromAPI "Position<>" whereas in UserClass it is necessary to write "Position", although there is the same typedef for both.**

change in ClassFromAPI results in:

```
error C2955: 'X::Y::Z::Position' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

change in UserClass results in:

```
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to write the classes from my API in an easy form instead of X::Y::Z::ClassFromAPI, I have actually achieved that, but I wonder why I have to write it in another form than a user, although there is the same typedef for both.

Comment: Name lookup in C++ is [a rather complex subject.](https://twitter.com/JamesMcNellis/status/336513318686695424)  The short and imprecise explanation is:  the compiler searches for the meaning of the name `Position` from the innermost namespace (`::X::Y::Z`) to the outermost namespace (the global namespace) and stops as soon as it finds something named `Position`.  The first thing named `Position` that it finds is the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `X::Y::Z::Position` template *shadows* the `::Position` typedef. It is invisible inside `X::Y::Z`.

You cannot use the same name to refer to a template and a type in the same scope. You need to change one of them.